# How to install a specific Nginx version from repository in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, repository, apt-get

I recently formated my ubuntu machine and am now having trouble in reinstalling Nginx on it. Before formatting I was running `nginx-1.4.7`. I had installed it from the nginx repository using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install nginx
```

But now the latest nginx stable version is `1.6.0` and I am not able to run it properly. It is giving me duplicate servers errors. Finally I have decided to install `1.4.7` but now the above commands will only install `1.6.0`. How do I install `1.4.7` again?

I am using following commands to uninstall nginx:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nginx
sudo apt-get --purge remove nginx
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo find / | grep nginx | sudo xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: The only way is to find deb file or build package yourself. But I would strongly suggest to find out what's wrong with 1.6 and fix it.

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong with `1.6.0`. Even if I restart my nginx service immediately after installing it (without changing the configuration), it gives me the duplicate server error.

Comment: There is no such error in nginx. What exactly nginx report?

Comment: This the error message in my `error.log`:`a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default~:21`

Comment: Remove backup files (ones ended with `~`). There is default server in `default` file and another in backup file `default~`.

Comment: ok let me try that... i am reinstalling `1.6.0`

Comment: @AlexeyTen there is no `default~` file in either `sites-available` or `sites-enabled`...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52493/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-surender-thakran)